# Exception in button tag

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have set the tags for the buttons but in this method i am getting an exception and i am not sure why

```
- (IBAction)showComments:(UIButton *)sender
{   
     int tag=[sender tag];
     NSLog(@"The tag clicked:%@",[blogids objectAtIndex:tag]);
}
```

Where blogids is my NSMutableArray

Thanks

Comment: What Error/Exception it gives?

Comment: it is showing this `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

Comment: post the error here then only we can understand

Comment: print the value of array and button tag

Comment: Check your `blogids` count and then try to access objects from array. It is beacause `tag` is grater than number of object in `blogids` array.

Comment: show the code which creates array blogids and also show the code which assigns tag to button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an exception is because your tag is greater then the blogids count.

Add the buttons to the array and then it will not crash.

For example:

```
blogids = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[blogids addObject:oneOfYourButtons];
```

Also if you only want to see the tags number use this:

```
NSLog(@"The tag clicked:%d",tag);
```

instead of:

```
NSLog(@"The tag clicked:%@",[blogids objectAtIndex:tag]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NSRangeException, which means you are trying to retrieve that element of array which is not existing. I suggest you should check the array count with Tag value which you are trying retrieve.

```
NSLog(@"%d",[blogids count]);
NSLog(@"%@",tag);
```

I am sure tag value is greater than count. That should not be, if you want to retrieve value from array using tag.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your blogids array is blank. Please check if it has object in the index you got from button tag

Answer (score 0):

Your `blogids` is empty array here. so that, it show as bounds as `[0 .. 0]`(that is array count is zero). Just check your array initialization.